# An Elementary Inequality

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, inequalities

A friend of mine found in the internet the following exercise:

Let $a, b, c \geq 0$ with $a + b + c = 1$. Show that
$$
\sqrt{a + b^2} + \sqrt{b + c^2} + \sqrt{c + a^2} \geq 2,
$$
where equality is attained only for the values
$$
(a, b, c) = (1, 0, 0), \ (0, 1, 0), \ (0, 0, 1),
\quad\text{and} \quad
\left(\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}\right).
$$
I managed to give a brute-force proof with the help of *Maple*: After squaring three times (in order to get rid of the square-roots) and setting
$c = 1 - a - b$, I arrived to an inequality involving a sixth-degree polynomial $h(a, b)$. Then the proof was accomplished by a careful study
of $h(a, b)$.

My question is whether there is a shorter, more natural proof.

Comment: this is answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2028729/87355

Comment: Fix b and c and take the derivative with respect to a. It is positive, hence the value is bigger that the value for a=0. Putting a=0 you arrive at an estimate being valid for all b and c in the interval (0,1).

Comment: @Echo Could you explain in more detail?

Comment: Another proof is given in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4332928/given-a-b-c-ge-0-abc-1-then-prove-sum-limits-cyc-sqrt